# Как в поле ввода text, создать ограничения на написания символов, кроме нужного списка?

Tags: python, python-3.x, gui, tkinter, валидация

Кода-примера нету. Есть только вопрос.

Допустим есть список символов:

```
'1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', '0', '.', '-'
```

Нужно, чтобы в поле ввода `text` могли вводиться **`только символы из списка`**.

Как это сделать?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ссылаясь на один из ваших предыдущих вопросов, это может выглядеть как-то так:

```
import tkinter as tk

window = tk.Tk()
window.title("Okno")

def validate(new_value):                             
    try: 
        if new_value == "" or new_value == "-" or new_value == "+":
            return True
        _str = str(float(new_value))
        return True
    except:
        return False    


que = tk.Label(window, text="Введите цифры")

vcmd = (window.register(validate), '%P')     
ans = tk.Entry(window, validate='key', validatecommand=vcmd)

que.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky="e")
ans.grid(row=0, column=1)
ans.focus()

window.mainloop()
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Большое спасибо!!